# iOS Charts Line Chart Missing Last Axis Label

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

I have created a line chart with the iOS Charts pod.

First off I have an array of custom objects called TestBalance which contain a dateString (which is converted to a Date) and an amount (Double). For the time being, I have created a hardcoded array like so.

```
let balanceTestArray : [TestBalance] = [TestBalance(dateString: "01/01/2019", amount: 1920.24), //More elements... , TestBalance(dateString: "28/01/2019", amount: 844.24)]
```

I then go onto creating the array of ChartDataEntry's for the graph data.

```
let now = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
let dayInterval: TimeInterval = 3600 * 24

guard let firstDate = balanceTestArray.first else {return}
guard let lastDate = balanceTestArray.last else {return}
guard let firstDateDateValue = firstDate.date else {
  print("No Date")
  return
}
guard let lastDateDateValue = lastDate.date else {
  print("No Date")
  return
}

let from = firstDateDateValue.timeIntervalSince1970
let to = lastDateDateValue.timeIntervalSince1970 + dayInterval
var counter = 0
let values = stride(from: from, to: to, by: dayInterval).map { (x) -> ChartDataEntry in
  let y = balanceTestArray[counter].amount
  counter += 1
  return ChartDataEntry(x: x, y: Double(y))
}
```

The above code seems to work great, plots all the points and the axis labels like so...

[Screenshot of graph from iOS simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvM8r.jpg)

I have setup my xAxis in the following way:

```
let xAxis = lineChartView.xAxis
xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 10)!
xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor(hex: "#A2A2A2FF")!
xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
xAxis.granularity = 1.0
xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = false
xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE dd"

let xValuesNumberFormatter = ChartXAxisFormatter()
xValuesNumberFormatter.dateFormatter = dateFormatter
xAxis.valueFormatter = xValuesNumberFormatter
```

This is where my 2 main problems start to show.

1. The first issue is the labels of the axis do not match up with the data, the spacing just seems off to me? Here is a picture zoomed in to the beginning of the data. How can I fix the spacing to max the data? I don't want there to be more than 1-day label for each value, whereas there are current 2 when zoomed in. Any solutions?

[Alignment issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z58XJ.jpg)

2. The second issue being, on the right-hand side of the graph the last date, in this case, the 28th Jan is not being displayed as a label but the data is showing? How do I get the label to appear?

Comment: You don't need to have a separate guard statement for each thing you're checking. You can do `guard let unwrappedThingOne = optionalThing, let unwrappedThingTwo = optionalThingTwo else {.return }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44916877/4475605

Comment: One more thing...Swift has some date calculation stuff built in so you're not ****ing around calculating the number of seconds. You can just declare current date like so: `let now = Date()` and you're done. Then you can create new dates like so: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-add-1-day-to-date-in-swift