# Cannot invoke initialiser for type with an argument of type Error

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I get the error

> Cannot invoke initialiser for type with an argument list of type `(xVals: [String]!, dataSet: BarChartDataSet)`

for below code on the highlighted line. Could you let me know how to sort this out.

```
var months: [String]!
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 9.0]
var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

  for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {            
      let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y:values[i])
      dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
  }

  let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
  let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSet: chartDataSet) //Error on this line       
  barChartView.data = chartData
```

Comment: can you add the char library link?

Comment: I guess the expected type is `[Double]` rather than `[String]`. Look up the type in the documentation. And why is `months` declared as implicit unwrapped optional? The value is clearly **non**-optional.

Comment: I have downloaded the libraries from below link https://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

Comment: Delete the ! From the declaration of `months`

Comment: @dacscan3669 please kindly review this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877031/difficulties-following-how-to-use-ios-charts-api-to-create-beautiful-charts-in/44878289#44878289 is the exactly same example as you are tying, please let me know if solves your problem

Comment: Thanks. The solution provided in the link helped!

Comment: The issue was resolved by solution provided in the below link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877031/difficulties-following-how-to-use-ios-charts-api-to-create-beautiful-charts-in/44878289#44878289